# Comparison of quality across different fundamentals data sources?

Tags: data, historical-data, fundamentals

There are a variety of different mechanisms and rules used by each fundamentals data provider to standardize and report company fundamentals. For example, the transformation of reported statements to quarterly statements.

Is there a study comparing the quality and tradeoffs of the techniques employed by the various fundamentals data providers?

Comment: Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

*I could not find a study about it.*

**BUT**

> "COMMERCIAL HISTORICAL DATA
>
> HIGHER RESOLUTION AND MORE COMPLETE DATASETS ARE GENERALLY NOT AVAILABLE FOR FREE. BELOW IS A LIST OF VENDORS **WHICH HAVE PASSED OUR QUALITY SCREENING (IN TOTAL, WE SCREENED OVER A DOZEN VENDORS)**. **TO QUALIFY, THE VENDOR MUST AGGREGATE DATA FROM ALL US NATIONAL/REGIONAL EXCHANGES AS ONLY COMPLETE DATASETS ARE SUITABLE FOR RESEARCH USE**
>
> **Caltech** did a good job of breaking down what was good and what was not. **"Ctrl-F" "errors" or "refresh rate"**

CalTech: [Quality of Stock Data](http://quant.caltech.edu/historical-stock-data.html)

Also this Answer did a great job [source of historical stock data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17263126/4237323)explaining it.

---

Edit:

**Quant Quote**[image: QuantQuote: See 7,8,9]

**SP Capital IQ** [image: SPCapitalIq(Compustat)]

Comment: Unfortunately, both of those links are for _stock market price data_. The question refers to _company fundamentals_ (or financials) data as a company would report annually on SEC Form 10-K and quarterly on SEC Form 10-Q. Specifically, the question concerns the techniques providers of this data employ to transform, for example, year-to-date to quarterly data (e.g. cash flow statements).

Comment: "Higher resolution and more complete datasets are generally not available for free. " Invite me to a chat so I can show you why that was a good answer. I cannot do all of your work for you. I will edit mine to show you what I was talking about. Please bold what you want, I understand you wanted fundamental equity, but there were 3 sources in there that provided it.

Comment: Did that help at all?